# Executing multiple python files with a simple command

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x, sockets

I have two executable files:

1. ./rclientSocket.py
2. ./rserverSocket.py

I need to execute rserverSocket first then rclientSocket using `rsocket 127.0.0.1 13005 "247 53 +"`

The arguments (127.0.0.1 ... ) should be executed with the both files.

**My approach**

1. Create Bash File?
2. Create python3 install.py setup?

Comment: Let me know if you have any question !

Comment: This is not Python nor programming related. The question fits any other two programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a bash file. Why to complicate things?

```
#!/bin/sh
python3 rserverSocket.py <args>
python3 rclientSocket.py <args>
```

Answer (score 0):

First question: Why do you want to make a script? Do you need to do this once, or many times? If the answer is once, then you're overthinking this and can just execute the two python scripts one after the other, passing the same arguments to each one. If the answer is you need to do this repeatedly, consider attempting a for loop in bash. You can assign your arguments to a variable 'args' and then use the bash loop syntax. Something like below could get you on the right track, but it's impossible to know how your scripts take arguments, etc. without more detail. Good luck.

```
for file in files 
do
args = "127.0.0.1"
rclientSocket.py -${args}
echo "${file} client socket complete"
rserverSocket.py -${args}
echo "${file} server socket complete"
done
```